# How can I search a bare Git repo for a string in the contents of the current revision?

Tags: git

Is it possible for Git to search the contents of the text files in a bare repository for a specific string?

I'm building a search feature for [WebGit .NET](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet) to allow for searching the current state of all repositories for text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that?

```
git grep -e textstring HEAD
```

or

```
git ls-files|xargs -I% -n 1 git cat-file -p HEAD:%|grep textstring
```

Comment: Greg, if you're around — you shouldn't have deleted your answer, the difference is that you have to specify treeish for bare repos.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for [`git grep`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-grep.html). When searching a bare repository, you must specify somewhere to search:

```
git grep foobar HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pick axe to see where in history the text was added or removed

```
git log --all -S'your text'
```

Comment: If you want to be sure, should you use `-G` instead of `-S`?